# Use Jquery AJAX to get PHP Object

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

To try and be as short and sweet, yet as descriptive as possible i am having issues grabbing a PHP Object through Jquery Ajax. 
I am a semi-new PHP developer and i have created an object containing some strings and variables as shown here:

*calculation.php*

```
$return = new stdClass;
$return->success = true;
$return->errorMessage = "Oops, something went wrong!";
$return->Score = number_format($scoreFromSheet,1);
$return->roi = number_format($roiFromSheet,1);
$return->dvScoreAnalysis = $scoreAnalysis;
$return->className = $className;
$json = json_encode($return);
echo $json;
```

I have constructed a very crude Ajax call to the PHP file to try to access the json_encoded object. As shown here:

*finalPage.php*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: './dvs_calculation/calculation.php',
        data: {data:data},
        success: function (json) {
            alert('working');
            console.log(json[0].Score);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        }
    });
});
```

I have echo'd the object to the DOM to display the output of my object, and it looks pretty solid:

*$json output*

```
{
    "success":true,
    "errorMessage":"Oops, something must've gone wrong!",
    "Score":"65.5",
    "roi":"25.8",
    "ScoreAnalysis":"High Deal Viability"
}
```

When using the Ajax function i receive a parse error and it prints out nothing from the success function. Not sure where i am going wrong. Any help or reference greatly appreciated.

Comment: Should be `json.Score`

Comment: What is the "parse error"?  What is the exact and entire response from the server?

Comment: You have `data: {data:data},` ... which, sounds ambiguous. Other than that, I am not seeing any syntax issues in the jquery :(

Comment: Sounds like something other than the `echo` is being output in the php. Inspect the actual response body in browser dev tools network to see exactly what gets sent

Comment: Do you have this example somewhere we can hit it and see the parse error ourselves?

Comment: Check the network tab in your browsers dev tools and see what the response from the called page actually is. Btw, not sure why you're passing "data" at all, since looking at your code, it will always be null.

Comment: The error thrown is: Request failed: parsererrorSyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input. @MagnusEriksson - you are correct in the response appears to be null in the network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Access the Score value from the json response as

```
json.Score //gives you the value of Score key from json
```

Also according to the code provided, you aren't passing anything to the php side as the data variable is just defined

Comment: ALthough probably correct has nothing to do with json parse error